# Javascript how to use getComputedStyle on an :active pseudo element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have tried to use getComputedStyle with other pseudo elements and they all worked. But when I try to get the property of :active it always reads the default value.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("test");
  var theCSSprop = window.getComputedStyle(elem, ":active").getPropertyValue("font-size");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = theCSSprop;
}
```

```css
div {
  cursor: pointer
}

div:active {
  font-size: 50pt;
}
```

```html
<div id="test" style="height: 50px;background-color: yellow;">Test Div</div>
<p><button onclick="myFunction()">Show :active font-size</button></p>
<p>The computed font size for div:active in the test div is: <span id="demo"></span></p>
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By specification getComputedStyle only accepts pseudo-elements as the second parameter.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

However, :active is not a pseudo-element but a pseudo-class.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Pseudo-classes_and_pseudo-elements

Comment: Also, an element is only active while it's being clicked on, the moment you let go of it, and your function runs, it's no longer active.